# How can I display python scripts in Dash Tabs?

Tags: python, html, json, plotly-dash

I have been trying to display several .py files in Dash. The goal is to have one tab per script. The scripts are too long to want to code them line per line and too long to want to just screen shot them for displaying as images, which is far from ideal anyway.

I have tried to simply print them using html.P but they lose line breaks. I've converted them to html hoping that dash could handle that code somehow. I found the convert-html-to-dash library, but it doesn't function. I've converted the html to json and have tried to send the json dict to the dashboard as a figure. All of these approaches seem to be way off.

Does anyone have a method for sharing .py code in a dashboard?

UPDATE/ADDITIONAL INFO:

I found the code below here: https://community.plotly.com/t/convert-html-to-dash-html-components/47328/4

I'm trying to read my html version of the code line by line into the converter function, but the code is outdated. How can I fix

AttributeError: 'cython_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'fromstring'

?

```
import ast
def convert_html_to_dash(html_code, dash_modules=None):
    """Convert standard html (as string) to Dash components.

    Looks into the list of dash_modules to find the right component (default to [html, dcc, dbc])."""
    from lxml.etree import ElementTree

    if dash_modules is None:
        from dash import html
        from dash import dcc

        dash_modules = [html, dcc]
        try:
            import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

            dash_modules.append(dbc)
        except ImportError:
            pass

    def find_component(name):
        for module in dash_modules:
            try:
                return getattr(module, name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise AttributeError(f"Could not find a dash widget for '{name}'")

    def parse_css(css):
        """Convert a style in ccs format to dictionary accepted by Dash"""
        return {k: v for style in css.strip(";").split(";") for k, v in [style.split(":")]}

    def parse_value(v):
        try:
            return ast.literal_eval(v)
        except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
            return v

    parsers = {"style": parse_css, "id": lambda x: x}

    def _convert(elem):
        comp = find_component(elem.tag.capitalize())
        children = [_convert(child) for child in elem]
        if not children:
            children = elem.text
        attribs = elem.attrib.copy()
        if "class" in attribs:
            attribs["className"] = attribs.pop("class")
        attribs = {k: parsers.get(k, parse_value)(v) for k, v in attribs.items()}

        return comp(children=children, **attribs)

    et = ElementTree.fromstring(html_code)

    return _convert(et)


file1 = open('exits.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('exits_dash.py', 'w')

count = 0
for line in file1:
    count += 1
    line_out = convert_html_to_dash(line)
    file2.writelines(line)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice Mantine component for this. You can see the details here: [Mantine code component](https://www.dash-mantine-components.com/components/code). For example:

```
import dash_mantine_components as dmc

dmc.Code(
    """from dash import Dash
import dash_mantine_components as dmc

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dmc.Button("Settings")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)""",
    block=True,
)
```

In addition Plotly provides a way to display code natively:
[Plotly code component](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/code)

Comment: Thank you! That works exactly like what I wanted. I'd tried `.Code ` before with no success, but the dash_mantine_components made all the difference. And dmc.Prism is even better.

Comment: Prism is very good I wasn't aware of that thanks for letting us know!